# Magical Record for package download

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, magicalrecord

I want to do the following:

- When someone opens the app for the first time, a default list of services is added to the Service entity.
- Then i use `AFNetworking` to download the new services and update the table. But that is done in the background.
- If there are any changes to a service, that gets updated in the Entity database.
- New services get added to the entity database.

I have a Service entity with the following fields:

```
@implementation Service

@dynamic name;
@dynamic image;
@dynamic sid;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic parent;
@dynamic machine_name;
@dynamic desc;
@end
```

How can I use Magical Record to do what I mentioned above?